# How to Get Date and Year from Date in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I've Date as 1/21/2014 18:07:13 in SQL.
And How to get Output as "January 2013" ?

Comment: Do it in your application layer, a datetime stored in a database has no inherent format, the format is simply a string representation of the date, and such formatting should not be handled by the database. If you **must** do this within SQL then please provide the DBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc) since the method will be different for different database systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on `SQL Server` you may try something like this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,getdate()) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @GarethD Thanks....:-) Happy? You are totally right though. I admit it is my habit and i know it is bad.

Comment: Thanks for Accurate Answer Giannis,In spite of Your Bad habit, It Worked :P